# Select control on second rig

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to transfer controls from one rig to another.
I think I have most of it figured out but I'm getting a bit stuck.
I have a function that I am feeding, the duplicated control that I want to attach as well as the list of controls from the original rig that I need to find to move the control to.

My issue is that I keep getting this error:

> Error: ValueError: file  line 132: More than one object matches name: Index_2_L_ctrl

I searched through everything and I'm pretty sure that there is only one thing named each, but I can't figure out how to list any additional items named the same way. Or better yet to get rid of them.
Here is my function; let me know if anything is unclear I will try to clarify:

```
 def spltString(wtlf, arr):   
    ndp = wtlf
    print ndp
    dlb = difflib.get_close_matches(ndp, arr)
    fil = dlb[0]
    cmds.pointConstraint(ndp, dlb[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the long names of the controls you want, rather than the short names.  That will disambiguate different copies of `Index_2_L_ctrl`

You can find all of the copies of the control like this:

```
controls = cmds.ls('Index_2_L_ctrl', long = True)
```

the results will be object names with the complete hierarchy prepended, like

```
|skeleton|pelvis|spine1|spine2|chest|r_arm|r_forearm
```

or whatever. `cmds.ls()` with the `long=True` flag will convert short names to long ones for you.

It's a good habit to use long names most of the time precisely because of the problems you're having.